# Probably of getting no hearts and at least one jack

Tags: probability

Two different cards are randomly drawn from a standard deck of $52$. Let $A$ be
the event (no hearts), and $B$ be the event (at least one $J$). Find $\mathbb P(A\text{ and }B)$.

I think I found the probability of getting at least one jack by doing $1 - \mathbb P (\text{no jack})$, where $\mathbb P(\text{no jack})$ would be $\binom{48}{2}/\binom{52}{2}$..is this correct?

And the prob. of getting no hearts would be $\binom{39}{2}/\binom{52}{2}$?

Without giving me the answer, can anyone guide me in solving this? Thanks

Edit: I think I may have got it.

$\mathbb P(A)=\mathbb P(A\text{ and }B\text{ complement}) + P(A\text{ and }B)$

I can find $\mathbb P(A\text{ and }B\text{ complement})$, is it simply $\binom{36}{2}/\binom{52}{2}$? Its the same as probability of getting no hearts but you take out the $3$ other jacks also. And with that you find $\mathbb P (A\text{ and }B\text{ complement})$ and can just solve for $\mathbb P(A\text{ and }B)$ since you know $\mathbb P(A)$?

Comment: I like it. (The "traditional" way would probably be to use $P(A\text{ and }B)=P(A)P(B|A)$, and then you would use the same sort of complement idea that you used in the first place, except now you'd have $_{36}C_2$ and $_{39}C_2$ since the hearts are gone.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the conditional probability. In other words, you want to find $\Pr(B|A)$, and then solve for $\Pr(BA)=\Pr(AB)=\Pr(B|A)*\Pr(A)$. So, what is the probability that you draw at least one jack given the fact that you do not draw any hearts?